# C++, Matrix class which parameter to use?

Tags: c++, class, matrix

in C++ I want to build a class that contains a matrix how could I do that?
I tried:

```
class TestMatrix {
    int r,c;
    int new Matrix;
};
```

but that didn't work, I will specify the matrix sizes using the builder for example if I get 3 and 4 I want to build a matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns

**Note**: I don't want to use vector only the normal matrix like in c

Comment: good reading http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Comment: remove the new key word... that is something used when working with pointers....

Comment: where is matrix defined?? a custom lib?

Answer (score 0):

A C-like C++ implementation would have you use:

```
class TestMatrix
{
    int r,c;
    int* m_Matrix;
};
```

You'll need, to get something workable:

- A constructor, ideally the only place you set `r` and `c`
- An assignment operator where you copy your matrix to a new one
- A copy constructor
- to be careful what you expose publicly or not and the impact

If you used

```
class TestMatrix
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_Matrix;
};
```

you'd get almost all of that for free, and only miss:

- checking the rows for identical length.